# Is ValueStack container thread-safe?

Tags: struts2, thread-safety, httprequest, valuestack, actioncontext

Action classes are thread-safe since Struts filter creates new action object for each request.

All the action objects along with variables will be stored in `ValueStack`. So, Is the `ValueStack` container thread-safe?

Could we able to take values form different action objects of different requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's thread-safe. When an action is instantiated a new `ValueStack` is created in the `ActionContext`.

The `ValueStack` is actually has a scope `action`. Everything that falls into it should be resolved by the one of the action instances. Other instances preserve their space for the new incoming variables.